# Performance issue in R: Increment Matrix Values using Another Character Vector

Tags: r, performance, matrix, indexing

**What I am trying to do:**
Given a character vector `"b"` increment each cell in a matrix `"a"` corresponding to the transition from `b[i]` to `b[i+1]`

```
a <- matrix(1:676,nrow=26,ncol=26)
tags <- sample(letters)
colnames(a) <- tags
rownames(a) <- tags

b <- c("a","k","l","c","a","k")
```

I'm expecting the following changes to occur:

```
a[b[1],b[2]] <- a[b[1],b[2]]+1
a[b[2],b[3]] <- a[b[2],b[3]]+1
a[b[3],b[4]] <- a[b[3],b[4]]+1
a[b[4],b[5]] <- a[b[4],b[5]]+1
a[b[5],b[6]] <- a[b[5],b[6]]+1
```

Note that a transition from "a" to "k" occurs twice meaning that the corresponding matrix cell in `a` should be incremented twice

Obviously, I am dealing with a much larger problem in which I can't afford to increment theses cells using the above method. Also, for performance reasons, I would like to avoid any solution involving a loop.

If I was dealing with numbers instead of characters I would have done the following:

```
  mylength <- length(b)
   b_ind <- nrow(a) * (as.numeric(b[2:mylength]) - 1) + as.numeric(b[1:(mylength-1)])
  a[b_ind] <- a[b_ind] + 1
```

However, I am dealing with characters meaning that factors like `b[2:mylength]) - 1` would render an incorrect value

I was thinking of solving the previous problem using the `"which()"` function like so:

```
which(rownames(a) %in% b[2:length(b)])
```

However, this gives the indexes in an unordered fashion. Plus, I am not sure if using which is the best option vis a vis performance

Comment: What if a loop gives the best performance?  Loops are not inherently slow in R.

Comment: I have a working loop implementation and it is unbelievably slow compared to the solution proposed below. The solution below just needs a little tweaking at the res[i1] <- res[i1]+1 part.

Comment: As a side note and having efficiency in mind, you should try and assign to `a` values of same `storage.mode` -- with "integer" `a`, your `a[b_ind] + 1` is "double" and, assigning it, it will copy the whole `a` to change it to "double" and replace. `a[b_ind] + 1L`, on the other hand, will not copy the whole "matrix" (unless `a` is referenced by another object too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a <- matrix(0,nrow=26,ncol=26)
tags <- sample(letters)
colnames(a) <- tags
rownames(a) <- tags

b <- c("a","k","l","c","a","k")

i = match(b[-length(b)], rownames(a)) + (match(b[-1], colnames(a)) - 1)*nrow(a)
tab <- table(i)
mynames <- as.integer(names(tab))
a[mynames] <- a[mynames] + tab
```

credit goes to  akrun and  alexis_laz

Comment: A modification would be to save `as.integer(names(tab))` in a variable to avoid converting `names(tab)` to "integer" twice as it has some cost. Also, consider experimenting with `tabulate` like `ui = unique(i); a[ui] = a[ui] + tabulate(match(i, ui))` as it can be much faster than (manipulating the output of )`table`

Answer (score 2):

We can try

```
i1 <- cbind(match(b[-length(b)], rownames(a)), match(b[-1], colnames(a)))
res <- a
res[i1] <- res[i1]+1
```

Comparing with the OP's approach

```
a[b[1],b[2]] <- a[b[1],b[2]]+1
a[b[2],b[3]] <- a[b[2],b[3]]+1
a[b[3],b[4]] <- a[b[3],b[4]]+1
identical(res, a)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This would also increment additional unwanted cells, I would have needed just the diagonal of a[b[-length(b)], b[-1]] to be incremented, which I addressed using single indexing as posted in my question

Comment: @lmlerith Are you talking about the previous one I posted or the new one with `cbind`

Comment: @lmlerith It is only updated 3 cells as in your post

Comment: exchanging the place of match(b[-1], rownames(a)) and match(b[-length(b)], colnames(a)) in the cbind function seems to give the correct answer. Althought I have no idea how cbind works i'll have to test it out. Is match an ok function to use for performance? i'm new to R

Comment: @lmlerith Ohh, that was a stupid mistake from me.  Thanks for notifying that.  Here, the idea is to give row/column index to extract the cell and then update it.  It should be pretty fast though `cbind` can take away some of the efficiency.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't seem to work when you have a repeated transition in the vector "b". For instance: b <- c("a","k","l","c","a","k"). Here, the transition from "a" to "k" will be incremented in matrix "a" just once instead of two times.

Comment: @Imlerith : To account for multiple cases you could mix akrun's idea with yours to something like `i = match(b[-length(b)], rownames(a)) + (match(b[-1], colnames(a)) - 1)*nrow(a); tab = table(i)` and, then, increment the `as.integer(names(tab))` indices of `a` with `tab`. You could, also, `aggregate` (or anything similar) on `i1` "matrix"  to tabulate the number of transitions but it adds unnessecary computation time. A faster alternative to `table` would be `tabulate(match(i, unique(i)))` and increment the `unique(i)` indices of `a`.

Comment: @alexis_laz You could post that as a solution.